# newly joined array is missing an element - vb

Tags: vb.net, array-merge

I am trying to merge my 2 arrays,
`Dim arr1(3) As String`
        `arr1(0) = "a"`
        `arr1(1) = "b"`
        `arr1(2) = "c"`
        `arr1(3) = "d"`

`Dim arr2(4) As String`
        `arr2(0) = "a"`
        `arr2(1) = "x"`
        `arr2(2) = "x"`
        `arr2(3) = "b"`
        `arr2(4) = "z"`

`Dim arr3 As String()`
        `ReDim arr3(UBound(arr1) + UBound(arr2) + 1)`

```
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        arr3(i * 2) = arr1(i)
        arr3(i * 2 + 1) = arr2(i)
        Label8.Text = String.Join(",", arr3)
```

what happens after merging it is to print it's single values only

`Dim r = From s In arr3`
        `Group By s Into Group, Count()`
        `Where Count = 1` 
        `Select s`
        `Order By s`
            `Label9.Text = String.Join(",", r)`
        `Next i`

buy it only prints `,c,d`, it should print all single elements occurring once in both 2 arrays after merging them which should be `c,d,z`. What is wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: hello @preciousbetine, `c,d,z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two source arrays can have different upper bounds, you will have to iterate by using the higher of the two and also make sure not to access indexes outside of the bounds of the shorter array

```
Dim arr1() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
Dim arr2() As String = {"a", "x", "x", "b", "z"}

Dim arr3(arr1.Length + arr2.Length - 1) As String

Dim iDestination As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Max(UBound(arr1), UBound(arr2))
    If i <= UBound(arr1) Then
        arr3(iDestination) = arr1(i)
        iDestination += 1
    End If
    If i <= UBound(arr2) Then
        arr3(iDestination) = arr2(i)
        iDestination += 1
    End If
Next
```

This interleaves the results as you did.

---

If interleaving is not required and you are simply interested in the result (rather than in an algorithm), you can simply do:

```
Dim arr1() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
Dim arr2() As String = {"a", "x", "x", "b", "z"}

Dim r = From s In arr1.Concat(arr2)
    Group By s Into Group, Count()
    Where Count = 1 Select s
    Order By s
```

This returns the elements occurring exactly once in either `arr1` or `arr2`.

Comment: Maybe the OP's looking for `Union` and `Concat`? `Dim arr3 = arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray()` the values of both arrays, `Dim arr4 = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray()` all the distinct values.

Comment: If he is learning he wants an algorithm. Otherwise `Concat` with his `GroupBy`.

Comment: Do you mean that the OP wants to lose the `z` while merging the arrays? This detail should be clarified. One may assume it was a a mistake in the original *algorithm*. (Oh, well, you removed that part of the comment now, still intersting what the desired result should be).

Comment: It was a mistake in the original algorithm. Both of my solutions return `c, d, z`. My first solution shows how to interleave the two sequences as in his algorithm. Not sure what he wants so.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, sorry for not clarifying my desired output as it leave out a question. But you're right i'm only "simply interested in the result...elements occurring exactly once in either `arr1` or `arr2`". `c,d,z` only. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `Array.CopyTo`

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim arr1(3) As String
    arr1(0) = "a"
    arr1(1) = "b"
    arr1(2) = "c"
    arr1(3) = "d"

    Dim arr2(4) As String
    arr2(0) = "a"
    arr2(1) = "x"
    arr2(2) = "x"
    arr2(3) = "b"
    arr2(4) = "z"

    Dim arr3 As String()
    ReDim arr3(arr1.Length + arr2.Length)

    arr1.CopyTo(arr3, 0)
    arr2.CopyTo(arr3, arr1.Length)

    For Each s As String In arr3
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub
```